# upload data from MicrosoftSQLServer to Google BigQuery

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery

Is their any way to upload data from MicrosoftSQLServer to Google BigQuery with a single API (without using Google Cloud In between)?

Answer (score 1):

We did this with bulk download to CSV, and then upload that CSV.

There's no more native solution currently, unfortunately